# Change of Variables: Transforming D* into D

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Let x=u+v, y=u-v.

If D is the region 0 is less than or equal to y which is less than or equal to x which is less than or equal to 1, what is the region D* that maps onto D?

I know that if you are taking a 1-1 map of D* onto D, then you have the double integral of (u+v) times (u-v), but I'm not quite sure the role that the Jacobian plays in this? Can someone guide me through the steps to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Your change of variables rotates the reference frame 45 degrees, and at the same time dilates it.  The Jacobian will tell you the degree of compression / dilation.

Answer (score 1):

$D=\{(x,y): 0<y<x<1\}$ is the region in red below.

The vertices are $(0,0), (1,1)$ and $(1,0)$

$D^*:$ In u,v space these vertices map to $(0,0), (1,0), (\frac 12, \frac 12)$ respectively.

Plotting this region on the same set of axes, the red region in $x,y$ space maps to the green region in $u,v$ space.

[image]

The jacobian $\left|\begin{array}{}
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac {\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac {\partial y}{\partial v}\end{array}\right| =  2$

$\int_0^1\int_0^x xy \ dy\ dx = \int_0^{\frac 12} \int_v^{1-v} 2 (u^2 - v^2) \ du\ dv$

Comment: can you assume the function is xy?

Comment: You say that you had $\int (u+v)(u-v) du dv$  and $x = u+v, y = u-v$